# vue-Chart.js - When I add data, charts are not updated

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

vue-Chart.js - After I hit add data to my chart via addchart button, but the number of charts is not increasing but my data count is increasing. i have tried many ways but i can't fix it, anyone please help me to fix my code Thank you for helping I am hands on programming using vue.js if anyone can help me.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Vue-Chartsjs</h1>
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- <Bar
        id="my-chart-id"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :data="chartData"
        ref="chart"
      /> -->
      <Bar
        id="my-chart-id"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :data="chartData"
        ref="chart"
      />
      <div class="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="addchart">
          Add Chart
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="delchart">
          Delete Chart
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <pre>
      {{ this.chartData.datasets }}
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- <script>
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale
);
export default {
  components: { Bar },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)",
            data: [40, 20, 12],
          },
        ],
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    addchart() {
      this.chartData.datasets.push({
        label: "Data",
        backgroundColor: "#f87979",
        data: [40, 20, 12],
      });
    },
    delchart() {
      this.chartData.datasets.pop();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    
  },
};
</script> -->

<script>
const chartData = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dataset 1",
      data: [20, 5, 4, 8, 10, 4, 7],
      backgroundColor: "#DB4C77",
    },
  ],
};

import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
} from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale
);

export default {
  components: {
    Bar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: chartData,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addchart() {
      const newDataChart = {
        label: "Dataset 1",
        data: [2, 5, 4, 8, 10, 4, 7],
        backgroundColor: "#DB4C77",
      };
      // chartData.datasets.push(newDataChart)
      this.chartData.datasets.push(newDataChart);
    },
    delchart() {
      this.chartData.datasets.pop();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
div {
  text-align: center;
}
.bar {
  width: 70rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #fff;
}
.buttons button {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

thanks for the answer

Comment: You don't call chart.update(); https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: I tried using chart.update(); but not available

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to rebuild the whole `chartData` object *and* the `chartData.datasets` array for change detection to work:

```
addchart() {
  const newSet = ...
  this.chartData = {...this.chartData, datasets: [...this.chartData.datasets, newSet]}
  }
},
```

Rebuilding only the object or only the array does not seem to work, it has to be both (and probably every other object you want to update).

Have a look at the [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

---

Alternatively, you can extract `datasets` into its own property and turn `chartData` into a computed value:

```
  data() {
    return {
      datasets: [...],
  },
  computed:{
    chartData(){
      return {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"],
        datasets: [...this.datasets],
      }
    }
  },
```

Now `chartData` is automatically rebuild whenever a referenced data value changes. This is probably the better pattern, as it reads more clearly and is easier to extend.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)