# How can I update my VueJS barchart using this.$refs.bar.chart.update()?

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

VueJS Barchart refuses to update on data change

I tried to force the changes using `this.$refs.bar.chart.update()` after adding the ref to my bar component. Yet the function didn't seem to be recognized and I'd get `update is not a function` after running. I'm using Vue3 with the Options API.

I've also tried to use the render function but I had a similar error `render is not a function`. I also tried to follow the documentation by adding the data to a computed property. But nothing changed either.
I would have a data element inside my state and then I'd return it inside a computed property that would be passed into the bar component.

My code has to apply the changes on a checkbox check. the function `setData` creates the dataset field

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <Bar ref="chart" :key="value" :data="newData" :options="options" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  BarElement,
  Legend
} from 'chart.js'
ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
)
import graphData from '../../data/GraphData.json'
export default {
  components: {
    Bar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: 1,
      text: 'Multikills',
      data: {
        labels: [
          'Romex Fortrex',
          'OBG BotGapped',
          'Hou Max',
          'OBG Logic',
          'OBG Thanagor'
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Two',
            data: [15, 20, 5, 8, 15],
            backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6'
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        elements: {
          line: {
            borderColor: 'white'
          }
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            ticks: {
              color: 'white',
              font: {
                family: 'MarkPro',
                weight: 'bold'
              }
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              color: 'white',
              text: 'Winrate',
              font: {
                family: 'MarkPro',
                size: 14,
                weight: 'bold'
              }
            }
          },
          x: {
            ticks: {
              color: 'white',
              font: {
                family: 'MarkPro',
                weight: 'bold'
              }
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              color: 'white',
              text: 'Number of games',
              font: {
                family: 'MarkPro',
                size: 14,
                weight: 'bold'
              }
            }
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              color: 'white', // Set the text color
              font: {
                family: 'MarkPro',
                weight: 'bold'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    newData() {
      return this.data
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setData(value) {
      if (value.length > 0 && value.length < 5) {
        value.forEach(val => {
          if (val.selected == true) {
            const exist = this.data.datasets.find(el => el.label == val.label)
            console.log(exist)
            console.log(graphData)
            if (!exist) {
              const obj = {
                label: val.label,
                data: graphData.data[this.text][val.label],
                backgroundColor: this.generateColor()
              }
              this.data.datasets.push(obj)
            }
          } else if (val.selected == false) {
            console.log('in else')
            console.log(val.id)
            this.data.datasets = this.data.datasets.filter(
              dataset => dataset.label != val.label
            )
          }
        })
      } else this.data.datasets = []
      this.$refs.chart.update()
    },
    generateColor() {
      const red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 100
      const green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 100
      const blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 100
      const hex = `#${red.toString(16)}${green.toString(16)}${blue.toString(
        16
      )}`
      return hex
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, your code is not readable. Please format it

Comment: If you willing to update data without using a template ref, have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76234815/vue-chart-js-when-i-add-data-charts-are-not-updated/76255687#76255687)

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I'm new to stack overflow. It doesn't work with JS only since I'm using v5. What I did is I added a key prop to the chart so each time I'd check a checkbox. It'd create a new graph. I don't really know if it's a best practice but it works